# Creating new FlowFile or reusing old one

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am writing a custom processor, in which I transform the content of the FlowFile. For simplicity in this question, it shall just write the same content.

```
public void onTrigger(ProcessContext context, ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
  FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
  if (flowFile == null) return;

  session.write(
             flowFile,
             (input, output) -> input.transferTo(output) // Do transfomration here
  );
  session.transfer(REL_SUCCESS, flowFile);
}
```

If I am right, what I do there, is replacing the content of the original FlowFile by - in this case the identity of the content.

Now there is this methode

```
session.create(flowFile);
```

which creates a new FlowFile.

This made me think, whether I am doing it all wrong, writing in the original FlowFile. Doing it is so simple, so it feels ok. But maybe it would be better to create a new FlowFile?
**What are the implications of both ways and when is it correct to chose the one or the other? Or will the observable behavior be the same?**

This would be some code, which creates a new FlowFile, writing the content of the original one:

```
public void onTrigger(ProcessContext context, ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
  FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
  if (flowFile == null) return;

  FlowFile newFile = session.create(flowFile);
  session.write(
             newFile,
             output) -> session.read(flowFile).transferTo(output) // Do transfomration here
  );
  session.transfer(REL_SUCCESS, newFile);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it depends on your requirement, but in general you should write in the original FlowFile.

if you make a new flowfile with `session.create()` , a new UUID will be associated to your flowfile and it will make your data provenance messy for nothing.

Making a new flowFile is worth when :
- you want to keep both flowfile, the original and the new one
- read from external source (kafka, hdfs, FS ...)
- 1 input N output (for example splitRecords processor)

Answer (score 4):

- [session.write(flowFile, callback)](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.11.4/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html#write-org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile-org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback-) - Executes the given callback against the content corresponding to the given flowFile.

  - Useful when you don't need the original content.
- [session.create()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.11.4/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html#create--) - Creates a new FlowFile in the repository with no content and without any linkage to a parent FlowFile.

  - This method is appropriate only when data is received or created from an external system.
- [session.create(parentFlowFile)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/latest/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html) - Creates a new FlowFile in the repository with no content but with a parent linkage to parentFlowFile. The newly created FlowFile will inherit all of the parent's attributes except for the UUID.

  - Use when you want to output both - the original flowfile and the new one.
  - Or you want to create multiple flow files from input.

Comment: Thank you! This provides useful information. It was a difficult decision, which answer to accept.